# Missing Property in Windows 8 Phone TextBox

Tags: c#, properties, textbox, visual-studio-2013

although i am an experienced developer, i am a newbie to Win 8 Phone.

My problem are missing properties, which i can find in the help, but when i try to use them, the compiler generates errors.

Some examples for TextBox:
 
**CharacterCasing** and **Passwordchar** are unknown the the compiler.
**AcceptsReturn** is recognized, whereas **AcceptsTab** is not.
The last gave me the idea, that this makes sense only on desktop apps, but the other properties ..?

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013 V 12.0.30110.00 Update 1.
I startet developing with Visual Studio 2010 Express, could that interfere?

Tia